# Program continues even though password/user are invalid

Tags: c++

i've implemented a Vending Machine which has 2 modes, Admin and User. In order to get access to the Admin panel, a user and a password are requested. My problem is that even if the user and password are wrong, the admin panel can still be accessed. Here are my code files:

```
    //Login class 
         class Login
         {
         public:
         Login(); // constructor initializes data members
         bool LoginUser(User &u); // attempts to authenticate user
     };

    //LoginInfo class
      class LoginInfo
     {
      private:
      string userID;
      string password;
      public:

       LoginInfo(); // constructor sets attributes 
       bool validateUser(string name, string password);
     };

     // User class
      class User {
      private:
      string id;
      string password;
      public:
      User(string a, string pass);
      User();
      string getId();
      string getPassword();
     };



     //Login.cpp
         Login::Login() {};

    bool Login::LoginUser(User &u)
{
    LoginInfo linfo;
    string Id = u.getId();
    string pass = u.getPassword();
    bool login = false;
    if (linfo.validateUser(Id, pass)) {
        cout << "\nWelcome!";
        cout << "\nAuthenticated!\n";
        login = true;
    }
    else
        cout << "Invalid user ID or password. Please try again.";

    return login;


}; 

//LoginInfo.cpp
#include "LoginInfo.h"
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

LoginInfo::LoginInfo()
{
    userID = "Mark";
    password = "1234";
};

bool LoginInfo::validateUser(string name, string pass)
{
    bool validUser = false;
    if (!(name.compare(userID))) {
        if (!(password.compare(pass))) {
            validUser = true;
        }
    }
    return validUser;
}

 //User.cpp
#include "User.h" 
using namespace std;


User::User(string lId, string lpass) : id(lId), password(lpass) {}

User::User() {
    cout << "\nEnter UserID :";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "\nEnter password :";
    cin >> password;
}


string User::getId() { return id; };
string User::getPassword() { return password; };

  //main.cpp



 void Vending::adminMode()
{
    unsigned userInput = 0; // user has not chosen to exit
                             // loop while user has not chosen option to exit system
    while (!userInput)

    {
        User u;
        Login l;
        bool login = l.LoginUser(u);
        cout << "\n Continue = 1 , Exit  = 0 : ";
        cin >> userInput;

        if (login = true)
        {

            continue;
        }


        else if (userInput == 0)
        {
            cout << "\n You have exited Admin Mode" << endl;
            testMachine();
        }


    }

    int choice;
    cout << "ADMIN MODE" << endl << endl;



    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Please select an option: " << endl << endl;
        cout << "1 ----- Add new drink type" << endl;
        cout << "2 ----- Restock drink" << endl;
        cout << "3 ----- Edit existing Drink" << endl;
        cout << "4 ----- Print machine status" << endl;
        cout << "0 ----- Quit Maintenance mode" << endl << endl;
        cout << "User Input: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
```

If i enter a wrong password/user, i can still choose 1 as input and get to the Admin Menu. If the password/user are incorrect, it should prompt the user back to insert them again but i don't know where the issue lies.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Also it sounds like you should (learn to) use a debugger to step through your code

Comment: You may want to reconsider the logic in `validateUser`. Edit: Draw a truth table to see what I mean

Comment: `if (login = true)`.......

Comment: Please read up on references and const

Comment: Don't mix up assignment (`=`) and comparision for equality (`==`)

Comment: That code is neither complete nor minimal.  Please edit it so that it compiles cleanly, without anything that's not necessary for demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Your logic in `adminMode()` is wonky. When `login == true` shouldn't that be a `break` instead of `continue`? And the `else` should have a `return` instead of a function call. Not 100% sure without seeing all the code. Also, you never check if anything other than `0` is entered.

Comment: My logic was that if the login == true, then you would be able to continue to the Admin Mode, i have chosen a function call in the else because if the user chooses 0 to exit the admin mode, it gets him back to the main menu, where he has to choose again between admin mode and customer mode. I would put all the code but it's a very large piece of code, i've only put the parts that are involved in my issue.

Comment: You need to look up how [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) works.

Comment: I have tried using break instead of continue and i get the same result.

Comment: another thing i've noticed is that if i remove if the login==true and else, the program still works and i still can go through the admin panel the same way as i did with the statements.

Comment: See if this [mcve] helps: https://ideone.com/nvlEju

Comment: Yes, yours works very nicely. I just have to adjust it to mine, since i'm using different classes. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The error lies in:

```
if (login = true)
{
     continue;
}
```

You probably want to use:

```
if (login == true)
{
     continue;
}
```

The first case means an assignment and will always be true, the second case is actually testing whether the value is true or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried that and unfortunately i get the same result. I still get the choice to continue or exit and if i press continue it still goes through the admin panel.

Comment: let me look at other errors in your code

Comment: where is the `compare` function that you are using?

Comment: i am not using any compare function.

Comment: sorry, you are using std::string::compare

Comment: ah, yes. i thought you meant checking the user and password through an if statement. I also tried adding another condition in the if else loop; if login==false, return to login again, but it still didn't work